# How to execute a command in a new terminal and capture and print the content displayed in the new terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, tty, xterm

I am able to run a command in the new terminal using

`gnome-terminal -e tty`

or

`xterm -hold -e tty &`

now that the results in the new terminal would be

`/dev/pts/2`

I want this to be output to the terminal from which i executed the above command (`xterm -hold -e tty &`), i am trying to do it with python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see output in the terminal from which you call another terminal to run a command, why not execute the command in the calling terminal in the first place ? But perhaps you have your reasons. I'd suggest using a file to output the command to that file, and then `cat` it inside the calling terminal.

`xterm -hold -e 'tty 2&>1 testfile' ; sleep 1; cat testfile`

Perhaps using && operand will be a better option if you have a command that will take some time to run
`xterm -hold -e 'tty 2&>1 testfile' && cat testfile`